# Hide class template instance based on traits

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, sfinae

I have a traits class like the following that reflects the compatibility between two types:

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename ArgumentType>
struct Traits
{
    static const bool SpecialMethodAvailable = false;
};
```

The single member determines if `SpecialMethod()` can be called on objects of type `ObjectType` with argument of type `ArgumentType`.

A simple class that supports this is the following:

```
class ClassWithSpecialMethod
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void SpecialMethod(T param) { std::cout << "Special Method called with " << param << std::endl; }
};

template <typename ArgumentType>
struct Traits<ClassWithSpecialMethod, ArgumentType>
{
    static const bool SpecialMethodAvailable = true;
};
```

I want to write a worker class that uses this traits class and calls the special method if it is available. Basically something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct Worker
{
    static void DoSomething(T t, GlobalDataType& globalData)
    {
        //if Traits<GlobalDataType, T>::SpecialMethodAvailable
        //    call the method
        //else
        //    do something different
    }
};
```

I tried to realize this using `std::enable_if`. My solution works with the Visual C 14.1 compiler but not with GCC. Here is what I tried:

```
template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct Worker
{
    static void DoSomething(T t, GlobalDataType& globalData)
    {
        std::cout << "There is no special method (called with " << t << ")" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Worker<T, typename std::enable_if<Traits<GlobalDataType, T>::SpecialMethodAvailable>::type>
{
    static void DoSomething(T t, GlobalDataType& globalData)
    {
        globalData.SpecialMethod(t);
    }
};
```

I used this as follows:

```
typedef ... GlobalDataType; //before the template declarations

int main()
{
    GlobalDataType td;

    int integer = 0;
    Worker<int>::DoSomething(integer, td);
}
```

If `GlobalDataType` is typedef'ed to `ClassWithSpecialMethod`, both VS and GCC compile fine and output correctly:

```
Special Method called with 0
```

However, if `GlobalDataType` is typedef'ed to something that does not allow the special method (e.g. `int`), VS still produces the correct output while GCC results in a compile error:

> In static member function ‘static void Worker::SpecialMethodAvailable>::type>::DoSomething(T, GlobalDataType&)’:
>   source.cpp:38:15: error: request for member ‘SpecialMethod’ in ‘globalData’, which is of non-class type
>   GlobalDataType {aka int}’

Can someone explain why this does not work as intended under GCC? What would be alternatives?

[Link to online compiler](http://cpp.sh/4lka)

Comment: Notice that there [std::experimental::is_detected](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) to replace your traits with specialization: `template <typename T, typename Arg> using SpecialMethod_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().SpecialMethod(std::declval<Arg>()));` and then `template <typename T, typename Arg> using Traits = std::experimental::is_detected<SpecialMethod_t, T, Arg>;`.

Comment: @Raxvan: Even if your explanation is wrong/imprecise, your alternative implementation is still valid.

Comment: @Raxvan - I'm agree with Jarod42: I find your solution interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Jarod42, this method

```
static void DoSomething(T t, GlobalDataType& globalData)
{
    globalData.SpecialMethod(t);
}
```

with `GlobalDataType` fixed as `int`, is ever wrong (for ever `T` type) because it's sure that `int` is without `SpecialMethod()`.

To solve this problem with a minimum code change, you can templatize the second parameter

```
template <typename U>
 static void DoSomething(T t, U & globalData)
  { globalData.SpecialMethod(t); }
```

If you want that `DoSomething()` receive (as second parameter) only a `GlobalDataType`, you can impose it enabling `DoSomething` using SFINAE, only if `U` is `GlobalDataType`. Something as

```
template <typename U>
 static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, GlobalDataType>{}>
   DoSomething(T t, U & globalData)
 { globalData.SpecialMethod(t); }
```

> What would be alternatives?

I propose you a completely different way, based (following the `std::declval()` example) over declaration of functions.

First of all, a couple of template helper functions

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename ... Args>
constexpr auto withSpecialMethodHelper (int)
   -> decltype(std::declval<ObjectType>.SpecialMethod(std::declval<Args>...),
               std::true_type{} );

template <typename ... Args>
constexpr std::false_type withSpecialMethodHelper (long);
```

Now you can write the declaration of a template function that return `std::true_type` if `ObjectType` has a `SpecialMethod()` that can be called with a variadic list of arguments of type `Args...`

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename ... Args>
constexpr auto withSpecialMethod ()
   -> decltype( withSpecialMethodHelper<ObjectType, Args...>(0) );
```

or maybe better, as suggested by Jarod42, through `using`

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename ... Args>
using withSpecialMethod
   = decltype( withSpecialMethodHelper<ObjectType, Args...>(0) );
```

If you can use C++14, you can also define a `withSpecialMethod_v` template `constexpr` variable

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename ... Args>
constexpr bool withSpecialMethod_v
  = decltype(withSpecialMethod<ObjectType, Args...>())::value;
```

in case of declared function or

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename ... Args>
constexpr bool withSpecialMethod_v
   = withSpecialMethod<ObjectType, Args...>::value;
```

in case of `using`, that can simplify the use.

Now the `Worker` class and specialization become

```
template <typename T, bool = withSpecialMethod_v<GlobalDataType, T>>
struct Worker
 {
    static void DoSomething (T t, GlobalDataType & globalData)
    {
        std::cout << "There is no special method (called with " << t << ")"
         << std::endl;
    }
 };

template <typename T>
struct Worker<T, true>
 {
   template <typename U>
    static void DoSomething(T t, U & globalData)
    { globalData.SpecialMethod(t); }
 };
```

Comment: @Jarod42 - today I'm particularly dumb; you're right. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: @Jarod42 - I don't understand how to use `is_detected` is this context; about a final trait, do you mean a type traits that avoid the direct use of `decltype` and give an handy  `constexpr bool value`?

Comment: About `is_detected`, I provide it in Question comment. Final traits as `template <typename T, typename Arg> using Traits = decltype(withSpecialMethodHelper<ObjectType, Args...>(0));`, the `_v` version for `constexpr bool` as bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Mvsc 14 doesn't do the 2 phases look-up needed for template.

gcc does (and is correct).

`globalData.SpecialMethod(t);` is incorrect for any `t` immediatly so the error. (`globalData.SpecialMethod` is incorrect and doesn't depend of template parameter).

By post-pone the evaluation you might have what you want:

```
template <typename T>
struct Worker<T, std::enable_if_t<Traits<GlobalDataType, T>::SpecialMethodAvailable>>
{
    template <typename G, typename U>
    static void f(G& g, U& u)
    {
        g.SpecialMethod(u);
    }

    static void DoSomething(T t, GlobalDataType& globalData)
    {
        f(globalData, t);
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a93fbb5cc21f5584)